# Компиляция igzip для Windows

Tags: c++, c

добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как компилировать проект [igzip](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/igzip-a-high-performance-deflate-compressor-with-optimizations-for-genomic-data)?

Мне выдает ошибку:

```
$ make
Making object file obj0c/crc_utils.o
/nfs/site/disks/iots4/engineering/cai_isa/tools/yasm-hsw/yasm -f x64 -f elf64 -X gnu -g dwarf2 -D LINUX -I . -I c_code -I ../include -D MAJOR_VERSION=IGZIP0C c_code/crc_utils.asm -o obj0c/crc_utils.o
make: /nfs/site/disks/iots4/engineering/cai_isa/tools/yasm-hsw/yasm: Команда не найдена
Makefile:250: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «obj0c/crc_utils.o»
make: *** [obj0c/crc_utils.o] Ошибка 127
```

Для компиляции использую MSYS2.

Comment: Возникла новая ошибка:

Comment: $ make
g++ -shared -o libigzip0c.so sobj0c/common.o sobj0c/crc.o sobj0c/hufftables_c.o sobj0c/crc_utils.o sobj0c/hufftables.o sobj0c/igzip0c_body.o sobj0c/igzip0c_finish.o sobj0c/igzip1c_body.o sobj0c/igzip1c_finish.o sobj0c/init_stream.o
sobj0c/crc_utils.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:155: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «libigzip0c.so»
make: *** [libigzip0c.so] Ошибка 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` же впролне понятно пишет:

> yasm: Команда не найдена

нужно скачать (http://yasm.tortall.net/), поставить и поправить строчку в Makefile:

> YASM := /nfs/site/disks/iots4/engineering/cai_isa/tools/yasm-hsw/yasm
>   на тот путь куда вы скачали `yasm`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло. Возникла новая проблема. вы не по посмотрите.

Comment: $ make
g++ -shared -o libigzip0c.so sobj0c/common.o sobj0c/crc.o sobj0c/hufftables_c.o sobj0c/crc_utils.o sobj0c/hufftables.o sobj0c/igzip0c_body.o sobj0c/igzip0c_finish.o sobj0c/igzip1c_body.o sobj0c/igzip1c_finish.o sobj0c/init_stream.o
sobj0c/crc_utils.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:155: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «libigzip0c.so»
make: *** [libigzip0c.so] Ошибка 1

Comment: @lorents судя по флагам у вас создается elf файлы в результате, поэтому вряд ли cygwin подойдет для компиляции. нужен или настоящий linux или подсистема windows 10 для работы с elf

Comment: Это многое объясняет. Спасибо!